# 'Command' object has no attribute 'has_permissions'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    try:
        await member.kick(reason=reason)
        embed = discord.Embed(colour=maincolour)
        embed.title = f"**Member {member.mention} Kicked."
        embed.description = f"**Reason** » {reason}.\n**Status** » Successful!"
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    except:
            embed = discord.Embed(colour=maincolour)
            embed.title = "**Kick not successful."
            embed.description = "**Possible Errors:**\n» Insufficient Permissions (Requires Administrator)\n» Error with Bot."
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

On the line

```py
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
```

the error is `'Command' object has no attribute 'has_permissions'`.

How do I fix this error? This code works for my friend.

Comment: Can you show your imports?

Comment: What version of discord.py do you have installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `has_permissions` attribute doesn't go under commands. This is how this should be properly done.

```
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions

@client.command()
@has_permissions(administrator = True)  
async def test(ctx):
    pass

@test.error
async def test_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("Looks like you don't have the permissions.")
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! If you wouldn't mind, could you mark my answer as correct? Just helps me out a ton!

Comment: Done! Thank you once again.

Comment: Please may you also tell me the modules like MissingPermissions, InvalidParameters or something like that? Like most of them in discord.py.

Comment: There are just simply too many extensions in the ```discord.ext.commands``` library to list. I do recommend that you look at their list here. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=discord.ext.commands

Comment: Thanks! Will help alot.